# Google Translator Select box in Arabic

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I am developing a website where I utilize Google Translator.
Functionality is there, but the translator language option box is in Arabic.

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en'
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

```html
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

How can I make it appear in English?

Comment: Alas the snippet will not run here due to cookies.

Comment: It shows English for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ynquzr47/

Comment: [Take a look at other similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translator+language+select+option+box+language+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I believe it might have to do with your browser's local language perhaps?